# ReactJS Update state array and re-order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios, es6-promise

I'm new to ES6, ReactJS, so excuse my lack of knowledge. I'll take any advice onboard. 
I've created a ReactJS project which places pins on a map and when clicked it shows videos related to that pin.
I'm using WordPress and there are two different post types, Places and video. Places can have multiple videos and are connected via Advanced Custom Fields repeater field.

I'm using WordPress API to query places. It returns the place data along with what video data is connected and the order it is in. Next, I loop through the video ids and get further data and add to a state sources array. As the requests are asynchronous, the data isn't returning in the order I'm requesting, so the video data is out of the correct order. Is there a way I can make the state array store the data in desired order?

```
class PlacePopup extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state ={
            sources: [],
        } 

    }
        getAudioUrl = (props) => {

        this.props.audio.map((file , index) => {

            axios.get(`/wp-json/wp/v2/audio/${file.ID}`)
            .then(response => {

                this.setState({ sources: [...this.state.sources, response.data]}, function() {

                });


            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error);
            });
        })
    }
```

Comment: With my very limited knowledge of JS - you need the `await` operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: How do you want to sort the array? I mean by an id number, by ASC order of some name...¿?

Comment: @Rodius Props.audio array is the exact order I'd like to display them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
Promise.all(this.props.audio.map(file => axios.get(`/wp-json/wp/v2/audio/${file.ID}`))
  .then(responses => {
    this.setState({ sources: responses.map(x => x.data)}, function() {

    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error);
  });
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much. Apologies, I'm pretty new to Es6, can you explain `code` x => x.data `code` part please?

Comment: @jamessy It's an arrow function with implicit return. If you omit the curly braces (`{}`), then the value after `=>` will be returned. It's basically the same as `x => { return x.data; }`.